# lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in `initialize': Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run `rails generate paperclip user avatar`, I got this error

> create  db/migrate/20130806042409_add_attachment_avatar_to_users.rb
>   /home/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in `initialize': Permission denied - /home/tairy/Documents/sheqwang/db/migrate/20130806042409_add_attachment_avatar_to_users.rb (Errno::EACCES)

Comment: Please check the permission of corresponding folder and file using 
ls -l command on terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I gave all permission to the folder and solve the problem.